# Queries in MYsql Unknown column

Tags: mysql, database

I'm currently trying to create a query so that I can display which patients had an operation on a specific date, however I keep getting this problem

> [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'Patient.PatientSurname' in 'field list'

The query I am trying to implement is this

```
SELECT Patient.PatientSurname, 
  Patient.PatientSex, 
  Patent.PatientAge, 
  Doctor.DoctorSurname, 
  Doctor.DoctorSpecialism 
FROM Operation 
WHERE (Operation.Date = ‘21/12/2010’);
```

Is this possibly to do with indexing?

Here is my code for my Patient table

```
CREATE TABLE Patient 
(PatientCode VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
PatientSurname VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
PatientFirstName VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
PatientSex VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
PatientAge VARCHAR (3) NOT NULL,
PatientOccupation VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
PatientHeight VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
PatientWeight VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
PatientAddress VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PatientCode),
);


CREATE TABLE Operation 
(OperationCode VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL, 
 PatientCode VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL, 
 DoctorCode VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
Date DATETIME NOT NULL,
 Result VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL, 
OperationType VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (OperationCode), 
  FOREIGN KEY (PatientCode) REFERENCES Patient(PatientCode) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT, 
 FOREIGN KEY (DoctorCode) REFERENCES Doctor(DoctorCode) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT );
```

Comment: you seem to have forgotten to join the tables.

Comment: do you have tables `Patient` and `Doctor`? and you want it to join against `Operation`?

Comment: yeah I have them tables, would I need to re-do my code again in order to join them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is you are referencing tables `patients` and `doctor` that are not joined to the `operation` table.  You need to join to these other tables to get the data that you want. Based on the details that you have posted, you just need to join your tables:

```
SELECT p.PatientSurname, 
  p.PatientSex, 
  p.PatientAge, 
  d.DoctorSurname, 
  d.DoctorSpecialism 
FROM Operation o
INNER JOIN patient p 
  on o.PatientCode = p.PatientCode
INNER JOIN doctor d
  on o.DoctorCode = d.DoctorCode
WHERE o.Date = '12-21-2010';
```

If you need help learning join syntax, then here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks this worked great, i'll definitely need to do more revision in terms of how you join tables

Answer (score 0):

Your table `Patient` is actually called `Operation`.

Perhaps that is the source of your troubles.

Comment: That was a typo when typing out the code on here, apologies on my behalf

Comment: Please copy/paste your [testcase](http://sscce.org). Typing out introduces typos, evidently.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: removed code snippet.

Even with your clarification re: Operation vs Patient table, that query makes no sense. You reference 2 tables (let's ignore Operation, and focus on Patient and Doctor) while you only SELECT from one.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: What you need to do is paste sample table content here or into sqlfiddle.com and then we can understand what you're trying to accomplish, as well as your SHOW CREATE TABLE output for the 3 tables involved.

Comment: This is my operations table




CREATE TABLE Operation 
(OperationCode VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
PatientCode VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
DoctorCode VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
`Date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
Result VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
OperationType VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (OperationCode),
FOREIGN KEY (PatientCode)
REFERENCES Patient(PatientCode)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
FOREIGN KEY (DoctorCode)
REFERENCES Doctor(`DoctorCode`)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT

);

Comment: Yes, by JOINing them. Just paste your SHOW CREATE TABLE staements to get more clarification.